# How to make babel grunt work?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, babeljs

I have installed grunt-babel. Set up gruntfile. The babel task runs successfully (i get notification from grunt with no errors), but it doesnt produce any output. Any ideas?

Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');

grunt.initConfig({
...
babel: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    presets: ['es2015']
  },
  babel: {
    es6: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/',
          src: ['**/*.es6'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/es6-build'
          //ext: '.es6'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
...
});

grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'babel',
  'watch'
  ]);
 });
```

Package.json :

```
{
"name": "yo1",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {},
"repository": {},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
...
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": [
   "es2015"
 ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the solution but comparing with my Gruntfile.js I would suggest removing the `es6` and `babel` keys. If you have more than one target (server) for example just remove the `es6` key and replace `babel` with `server`.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');

grunt.initConfig({
...
babel: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    presets: ['es2015']
  },
  files: [
    {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/',
      src: ['**/*.js'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/es6-build'
      //ext: '.es6'
    }
  ]
},
...
});

grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'babel',
  'watch'
  ]);
 });
```